# Tikz: How to split Nodes and position Text in it

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have a really big problem:

I need a TikZ node that looks like that:

[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/79761558/nodeproblem.png]

but i have no idea how to split the node like that. Esecially the "more text" is a big problem. All i tried ended in errors. So I'm at the beginning again.
Can anybody out there help me please?.

my last code did look like that but didn't work...

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[name=data, rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split draw    splits=false, draw, rounded corners=5pt] {1 \nodepart{two} 2 \nodepart{three} 3    \nodepart{four} 4 \nodepart{five} 5 \nodepart{six} 6};
  \foreach \subnode in {1,...,5}% counter goes 1 to number_of_subnodes-1
  {\draw[dashed] ($(data.north east)!{\subnode*0.25}!(data.north west)$) -- ($(data.south east)!{\subnode*0.25}!(data.south west)$);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

One more Question:
Why is CMD not centered???

```
\node[name=data, rectangle split, very thick,
    rectangle split horizontal, 
    rectangle split parts=6, 
    rectangle split draw splits=true, 
    draw, rounded corners=2pt,
    label={[fill=white,inner sep=0pt,font=\tiny]center:Daten/Parameter},
    align=center,
    text width=2.5em,
    inner sep=2pt,
    font=\tiny] at (mega88) 
    {CMD\nodepart{two} ~ 
        \nodepart{three} ~    
        \nodepart{four} ~
        \nodepart{five} ~ 
        \nodepart{six}CS};
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) No need to add thanks, simply upvote any good answers you may receive.

Answer (score 9):

By default `rectangle split` has 4 parts, so if you need more, you have to explicitly fix them with `rectangle split parts=number_you_want`.

Second problem is `more text`. I used another node on top of splited one.
`\node[fill=white,inner sep=1pt]` draws a white background node, a little bit smaller than the previous one. The result is:

[image]

and the complete code to do it is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[name=data, rectangle split, 
         rectangle split horizontal, 
         rectangle split parts=6, 
         rectangle split draw splits=true, 
         draw, rounded corners=5pt] (main) 
        {text \nodepart{two} 2 
              \nodepart{three} 3    
              \nodepart{four} 4 
              \nodepart{five} 5 
              \nodepart{six} text};

\node[fill=white,inner sep=1pt] at (main.center) {more text};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You don't need to write anything inside parts 2 to 5, but I left there to show you how `more text` node covers them.

*EDIT: `more text` as a `label`.*

Another option would be to use `label` option instead of a second node. In fact `label` are like nodes, so you can fix their options. In this case you have to fix its width (via `minimum size` or `text width`) to be sure of covering the empty parts. If you want to use different size for filled and empty parts, use option `text width` for filled ones and `rectangle split empty part width` for empty ones. Empty parts are not declared, `textpart{two} ~` is not an empty part, it's a part with `~` (non breakable space) inside. If `text width` is wider than the text inside, it will be aligned to the left, so add `align=center` to place it centered in its space.

Now the code with all this suggestions

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[name=data, rectangle split, 
    rectangle split horizontal, 
    rectangle split parts=6, 
    rectangle split draw splits=true, 
    draw, rounded corners=5pt,
    text width=2cm,
    align=center,
    rectangle split empty part width=5mm,
    label={[fill=white,
            inner sep=1pt,
            text width=2.5cm,
            align=center]center:more text \dots},
    ] (main)    
    {CMD 
%   \nodepart{two} ~
%   \nodepart{three} ~     
%   \nodepart{four} ~
%   \nodepart{five} ~
    \nodepart{six} CS};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and the result

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Thanks a lot!
new problem: How to add a fixed width to the parts?!

Comment: @donLuigi: Your wellcome! Please look at second option, I think it's easier to use it than first one.

Comment: I'm |-| that faar away from usin Paint...
    "rectangle split empty part width=xyz"
why is there no
    "rectangle split part width=xyz"

Comment: @donLuigi: you can use `text width` to fix width of not empty parts.

Comment: @donLuigi: text whithin a node is left aligned by default but you can use `align=center` option to center it.